# Bunch of 14/2 cables. Which circuits do they go to?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a bunch of 14/2 cables coiled up next to the circuit breaker box in the basement. They are not connected to the circuit breaker box.  They are various circuits that run in the basement.  How do I figure out which wire goes to which circuit?  I had mixed results with a wire tester that is primarily used for cars.  The wires on the circuits aren’t hooked up to anything.  Just sticking out of their respective electrical boxes approximately 6 inches.  I tested with a sniffer and none of it is live.  Just wondering if someone has a good way to solve this problem.  Thank you.

Comment: If you think the other end is connected to lights/outlets properly, then can connect to 15 amp breaker in the panel and turn on the breaker and see what turns on.  Only use 15 amp breaker with 14 gauge wire.  Turn off the breaker and label the cable.  Use the ohm setting on a meter first on the cable to make sure the white and black is not connected together at the other end.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a continuity light or meter. Twist the black and white wire together, after stripping off the insulation, at one of the junction boxes. Then go to the coils of wire by the panel and,one at a time, connect the continuity light or meter leads to the black and white wires in a piece of cable untill you get the light to turn on or the meter to jump to 0 ohms. Then mark each end with some colored tape. Do this for all the wires.